# trying to understand xmpp

Tags: xmpp, openfire

xmpp is federated.  does that mean that as long as i connected to one xmpp server .example gtalk server. from there, i can communicate with any external jabber server in the world when sending "iq stanze" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

It works just like smtp. The jabber id contains the name of the Jabber Domain.

jabber_nickname@domain so your home jabber server can find the jabber ip of the domain and transfert your messages and requests

Comment: Well, not quite since SMTP is routed with a chain of servers and XMPP is federated server to server. +1

Comment: While we're being pedantic, it's also different in that XMPP uses an SRV record (_xmpp-server._tcp.[DOMAIN]) instead of MX.

Answer (score 1):

See, you can communicate with any jabber server and jabber client out there, unless some other rule, like a privacy rule, prohibits that.  That is not restricted to IQ stanzas only, but all type of stanzas (presence, message, iq).

So, if you send a message to your friend on jabber.org, it travels from your client to your server, to her server, to her client, assuming that all connections are up and alive.